# Hosting grails app in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, amazon-web-services

I did a very simple grails app and tried to push it to my tomcat.

I did:

```
grails war
```

and placed the resulting war file into my tomcat/webapps directory and restarted it. The war is named as `ec2.war`. I am able to hit `localhost:8080`. But I am not able to hit: `localhost:8080\ec2` - I get an `404` error code.

I'm getting the following stacktrace in catalina.out :

```
NFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ec2.war
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: stacktrace.log (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:207)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:131)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
        at org.apache.log4j.spi.OptionHandler$activateOptions.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.log4j.Log4jConfig.createFullstackTraceAppender(Log4jConfig.groovy:237)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.log4j.Log4jConfig.configure(Log4jConfig.groovy:201)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:226)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.log4j.Log4jConfig.initialize(Log4jConfig.groovy:70)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.log4j.web.util.Log4jConfigListener.contextInitialized(Log4jConfigListener.java:48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

What can be causing this error and how can I resolve it?

Note that tomcat runs in ec2 and here `localhost` refers to my public IP which in case `5.x.x.x.x`.

Comment: Localhost:8080/ec2 and check logs/catalina.out for error messages.

Comment: @crudolf: I have added the stacktrace part.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as off topic. Grails is a programming framework and there are numerous questions regarding deploying it to tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the ownership of your tomcat folder. Do a:

```
ls -lisa /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/
```

and check the ownership. If you just want to get it running, the easiest way is probably to do:

```
sudo chown -R root:root  /var/lib/tomcat
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/tomcat
```

and do a

```
sudo /var/lib/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

But this is not the most secure way :)

Comment: Oh the problem was with the permissions. Thanks a lot it works now.

Answer (score 1):

By default a Grails application tries to create a log file named `stacktrace.log` in whatever was the current directory when tomcat started up. So you have two options

1. Control which directory it starts up in, by putting a suitable `cd` in the startup script, and ensure that directory is writable by the user id that tomcat is running under or
2. Change your grails configuration to put stacktrace.log somewhere else (or not to create it at all). You do this in the `log4j` closure in `Config.groovy`, see the "full stacktraces" section in the [user guide chapter on logging config](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#logging) for details.